# A possibility of the theoretical derivation of Pauli's Exclusion Principle

Tags: pauli-exclusion-principle, spin-statistics

Pauli's exclusion principle tells us (in an informal language) that each and every electron in an atom is unique. When I searched for a derivation , I got nil everywhere (even the wiki site says only that it's equivalent to anti-symmetry of wave functions with respect to exchange). However the  concept of anti-symmetric wave functions is itself another aspect of the principle. 
So , my question is straight : can we derive the principle theoretically?
As I know , in mathematics uniqueness can indeed be proved rigorously by logic and reasoning, and this gives me a hope that the principle can be derived from sounder mathematical principles. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Theoretical Proof of Pauli's Exclusion Principle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/360140/)